# Polars - to_dicts(). Is the order of the List of Dictionaries guaranteed?

Tags: python, python-polars

I am leveraging the function `.to_dicts()` in my testing the resulting list of dictionaries has the same order as the dataframe.

```
df = pl.DataFrame(data={
    "name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"],
    "age": [30, 25, 35],
    "city": ["New York", "London", "Paris"],
}).sort(by=['name'], descending=True)

data = df.to_dicts()

for record in data:
    print(record)
```

Results in:

```
{'name': 'Charlie', 'age': 35, 'city': 'Paris'}
{'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25, 'city': 'London'}
{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 30, 'city': 'New York'}
```

Does anyone know if that is *guaranteed* to happen every time?

Comment: The documentation doesn't specify, but it's hard to imagine why it wouldn't.

Comment: Dataframe rows are ordered, and lists are ordered. What conceivable implementation would reorder them when converting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TLDR.* Yes.

This can be seen by inspecting [this](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/d80cebfd0c1ae8c33f36f836374ff3decdc75f30/py-polars/src/dataframe.rs#L768) underlying rust function, which maps over the indices of the DataFrame in order.